# UIImagePickerController ImageIO_PNG takes massive memory

Tags: ios, memory, png, uiimagepickercontroller

Although I resize my images once the UIImagePickerController has finished taking a photo, my instruments profile says that calls to ImageIO_PNG are taking massive amounts of memory (40 MB+) each time I take a photo. This is my code:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info  {
    @autoreleasepool {
        if (myImageView.image == nil) {

            myImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

            UIImage *topImage = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

            UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
            CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0,0,320,440);

            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( rect.size );
            // use the local image variable to draw in context
            [topImage drawInRect:rect];
            UIImage *topResized = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

            myImageView.image = topResized;
            image = nil;
            info = nil;

            [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
            [picker removeFromParentViewController];
```

Comment: For one thing, at the bottom of this block of code, topImage, info and picker are still referenced, so they're going to be locked in memory still.  Not sure why you're fetching image and topImage (which are in this case aliases to the same object)

Answer (score 0):

remove below line from your code that might help:

```
image = nil;
info = nil;
```

Comment: Could you explain briefly why it might help?

Comment: as image points the memory where image if stored . If we give it nil the the memory address get lost. And that image remains in memory. Like if we make image 'nil' then it will release nothing. Releasing will be like [nil release];